# String Flip doesnt work, cannot understand why? causes out of bounds exception

Tags: java, string

So the Idea is that a string of numbers is created, one of the characters is flipped between `1-->0` `0-->1` but the position of the character that is flipped is random

```
public class Lab9 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ScalesSolution s = new ScalesSolution("11111");
        s.println();
        s.SmallChange();
        s.println();
    }

}
```

`input = '11111'` output is any of the characters flipped to a 0 `output = '11101' or '10111'` for example

```
public void SmallChange() {
        String newP ="";
        int p = CS2004.UI(0, scasol.length()-1);
          char[] ch = new char[p];  
        scasol.getChars(0, p-1, ch, 0);
        String x =String.valueOf(ch);

        if (scasol.charAt(p) == 1) {
            newP ="0";
        }
        else {
            newP = "1";
        }
        scasol.getChars(p+1, scasol.length()-1, ch, 0);
        String y = String.valueOf(ch);
        x = x + newP + y;

    }
```

- note that CS2004.UI is a random uniformly distributed integer generator based on time.

Comment: `charAt` is probably returning a `char` (without knowing what `scasol`is) so comparing with `1`  will only be true if the character is CTRL-A (ASCII code `1`) - better compare to `'1'` Hint: use `substring()` instead of `getChars()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@user85421 was correct in suggesting it returned a `char`. 
and also when using `substring()` note that the end excess is exclusive (so `p-1` would just be `p`